# Как передать двумерный массив, созданный на стеке, в функцию, принимающую int**?

Tags: c, c++

Мне надо передать в функцию с прототипом:

```
void print(int **mt, int lines, int columns)
```

массив, созданный на стеке:

```
int tmp[3][3] = {
    {5, 1, 6},
    {3, 0, 4},
    {2, 0, 3}
};
```

Как это синтаксически верно записывается?

*UPD*:
Я отлично знаю, что массив можно создать разными способами. Но меня интересует строго:

- print( int ** // обратить внимание, что две звездочки
- int tmp[3][3] // обратить внимание, что объект на стеке

Comment: Если только это не учебное задание, я бы использовал int **temp c new и с последующим освобождением памяти. Или вектор векторов, тогда и память освобождать не придется.
В противном случае @smallFish прав.

Comment: @avp: Мне кажется, ваш код стоит вынести в ответ. (Он, кроме прочего, полезен как адаптер между двумя популярными форматами двумерных массивов.)

Comment: @VladD, OK. Перенес.

Comment: мне кажется, учитывая UPD, ответ @avp является именно ответом на поставленный вопрос. Потому что да, типы разные, и если прям не меняем-не меняем, то нужен адаптер.

Answer (score 8):

1. Вы не можете знать, где именно будет
       создан tmp, а где выделена память
       под его элементы. Компилятор может
       что-то писать в регистры, что-то в
       кучу, что-то в стек, гарантий нет.

   UPD: речь идет именно о том, что
   выражение int tmp[3][3] НЕ
   гарантирует, что память будет
   выделена на стеке.
2. Вопреки ощущениям, N-мерные массивы,
       где N > 1 в C/C++ не эквивалентны
       указателю на указатель (N раз).
       Связано это с тем, что `tmp[3][3]`
       имеет тип `int tmp[][3]`/`int
       (*tmp)[3]` и реально в памяти лежит
       одним массивом, длиной в 9 int.

   Т.е. `int[3][3]` в памяти лежит вот
   так: `int[3] int[3] int[3]`, а
   каждый из `int[3]` лежит в памяти
   как `int int int`

**Как следствие, это просто разные типы данных. И приведение к `int**`, даже через reinterpret_cast приведет к падению, т.к. фактически там нет `int**` никуда.**

Чтобы заработало, Вам следует изменить `void print(int **mt, int lines, int columns)` на `void print(int mt[][3], int lines, int columns)`. Или заняться "колдовством" с typedef-ами, и в итоге все равно поменять интерфейс функции или вариант хранения данных из tmp.

Если же Вы уверены, что все должно быть так, как оно есть, то можно сделать костыль.

```
int* newtmp = reinterpret_cast<int*>(tmp);
void print(int* tmp, int rows, int cols)
{
    for (unsigned x =0; x < rows; ++x)
    {
       for (unsigned y =0; y < cols; ++y)
       {
          cout << tmp[cols*x + y];
       }
    }
}
```

Но это костыль, потому что закладываться на то, как в памяти лежит какой-то тип (а мы как бы знаем, что tmp[N][K] будет лежать одним массивом длиной N*K) и ковырять его прямыми обращениями к памяти - архитектурное зло, за которое выгоняют из Хогвардса :)

**UPD: интерфейс функции print в любом случае не имеет никакого смысла при работе с объектами типа `int tmp[X][Y]`**

Comment: 1. Ваша версия print с другим типом указателя. В вашем используется int* , я же привел версию int**. Обратите внимание на то, что звездочек две, а не одна.

2. Я отлично знаю, что можно по-разному создать массив. Можно на стеке, можно в куче и т.д. и т.п. Но в данном варианте строго "int **" и строго на стеке "int tmp[3][3]".

Вопрос как раз и состоит в том, что, зная, что только п.2. и никаких вариаций, правильно передать tmp.

Comment: @sys_dev, "int tmp[3][3]" - это НЕ гарантирует создания на стеке, о чем я и написал. Это НЕ строго на стеке, именно об этом написано в моем ответе.
Про то, что `int tmp[3][3]` и `int**` - принципиально разные типы - я тоже написал. Я написал, как в памяти выглядит `int tmp[3][3]` и почему приведение его к `int**` бессмысленно. Соответственно, и интерфейс print становится бессмысленным. И я предложил 2 варианта, как его поменять, чтобы вернуть смысл. С костылем и без. Поэтому там предложен костыль, который позволит, зная организацию в памяти int[3][3], работать с ним через указатель.

Comment: @sys_dev, откровенно говоря, *стек тут вообще ни при чем* (стек к решению этой задачи никакого отношения не имеет).

--

Просто все мы знаем, что **на самом-то деле** данные при таком описании:

 `int tmp[3][3]` внутри функции, 

компилятор разместит  последовательно в стеке. 

Но ведь сам исходный код от того, где именно (стек, куча, область статических данных, разделяемый сегмент данных ...) в принципе может быть размещена эта последовательность int-ов при исполнении программы никак не изменится.

Comment: @avp, компилятор не обязан размещать это на стеке. Что-то может быть размещено, например, в регистрах, точно может. И, насколько я помню, он даже может разместить это на куче при определенных условиях. Мы по факту не управляем этими процессами. Т.е. на самом деле мы не знаем, где разместит это компилятор, но предполагаем, что скорее всего на стеке.

Comment: @smallFish, Вы говорите о каком-то абстрактном компиляторе.

 Реально же в регистрах (например, в архитектуре x86-64) передаются несколько первых параметров функции.

Однако, это ни на что (в смысле исходного кода) не влияет. В любом случае можно написать так:

    void f (int a) {
      printf ("a: %p %d\n", &a, a);
    }


В этом случае (увидев выражение взятия адреса аргумента) компилятор выделит место под вспомогательную переменную (в стеке) и скопирует в прологе функции в нее значение аргумента (из регистра).

Comment: @avp, мои слова про стек был просто формой занудства, к вопросу он отношения не имеет, но сам по себе, имхо, интересен, поэтому я и написал про него в первом абзаце. Однако да, программист языка C++ не управляет тем, где именно будет выделена память, если жестко не указывает директиву, вроде register. И это важно понимать, даже если мы знаем, что современные популярные реализации языка C++ и выделят такое на стеке, говорить "это я выделяю на стеке" программисту С++, имхо, неправильно, когда язык не гарантирует выделения на стеке.

Comment: Сделал я это просто "из любви к искусству") вдруг зародится дискуссия и я узнаю что-то новое. Или кто-то узнает что-то новое.

Answer (score 3):

[[@sys_dev](/users/14618/sys_dev)](/users/14618/sys_dev), если Вы уверены, что функция с таким прототипом будет правильно работать с той матрицей, что Вы описали, то вызывать ее можно, например, так:

```
    print((int **)&tmp[0][0], 3, 3);
```

Код правильно работающей `print()` с таким (дурацким для данного случая) прототипом может быть, скажем, такой:

```
void 
print(int **mt, int lines, int columns) 
{
  int *a = (int *)mt, i, j;  // просто приведем тип к подходящему для доступа к последовательно расположенным в памяти элементам массива

  for (i = 0; i < lines; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < columns; j++)
      printf("%d%c", *a++, j == columns - 1 ? '\n' : ' ');
}
```

---

А что делать, если функция print все же работает с данными, на самом деле соответствующими своему прототипу?

Тогда функция ожидает матрицу, на самом деле сконструированную в виде массива указателей на строки. Так часто делают, когда создают "динамические" матрицы (т.е. массив заранее неизвестного размера в куче).

Обычно код, создающий такую матрицу, это что-то вроде

```
int **create_matrix (int n_lines, int n_cols) {
    int **res = (int **)malloc(sizeof(*res) * n_lines * n_cols);
    if (res) {
       int i;
       for (i = 0; i < n_lines; i++)
          if (!(res[i] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(**res) * n_cols)))
             return 0;
    }
    return res;
}
```

И код функции `print()` будет, например, такой:

```
void print(int **mt, int lines, int columns) {
  for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
      printf("%d%c", mt[i][j], j == columns - 1 ? '\n' : ' ');
}
```

Тогда в вызывающей функции надо просто сделать массив-"переходник" (адаптер), из указателей на строки tmp и передать в print его.

```
  int *pt[3] = {&tmp[0][0], &tmp[1][0], &tmp[2][0]};
  print(pt, 3, 3);
```

Естественно, этот массив можно заполнять и динамически (в цикле)

```
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    pt[i] = &tmp[i][0];
```

**UPDATE**

И вот так еще можно писать (по крайней мере в `gcc 4.8.2`).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void print(int columns, int a[][columns], int lines) {
  int i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < columns; j++)
      printf("%d ", a[i][j]);
    puts("");
  }
}

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  int t[3][4] = {{1,2,3,4}, {5,6,7,8}, {21,22,23,24}};
  print(4, t, 3);

  return 0;
}
```

Обратите внимание, на описание параметра `int a[][columns]` в списке аргументов `print()` и *динамический* (по текущему значению тоже параметра `int columns`) его размер!

Вот при такой записи у компилятора появляется достаточно информации для вычисления адресов `a[i][j]`.

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ. А можете найти в стандарте строки, описывающие Ваш ответ?

Comment: @sys_dev, на здоровье :). 

А по поводу стандартов, так (к сожалению (или счастью?)) я не любитель [такой литературы](http://busybox.net/~landley/c99-draft.html).

(прочел когда-то K&R, и время от времени заглядываю [сюда](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.3/gcc/index.html#Top) и другие подобные ресурсы).

Comment: @avp, Очень сложно отметить какой-либо ответ по настоящему ответом. А я привык выбирать один из ответов! )

Comment: @sys_dev, мы не в школе, и отметки тут роли не играют. 

Лучше вооружитесь любимым текстовым редактором, компилятором (в т.ч. с опцией для получения ассемблерного кода) и отладчиком, да и поизучайте, что практически происходит в разных случаях.

Comment: @avp, Всегда это делаю. Т.к. разрабатываю защиты ПО и мне куда роднее маш.код. Но, видя, что стековая переменная не работает с print() методом, меня действительно удивляет. Как правило, компиляторы строят sub esp, <размер всех-локальных переменных> и адресуются mov eax, [ebp+смещение локальной переменной]. Весьма удивительно, что код print не работает. Никогда бы не заподозрил в этой ситуации подвоха.

Comment: @sys_dev, а я ведь здорово всех тут обманул (недорассказал).

Что-то подсказало мне попробовать одну штучку с новым `gcc`. И надо же, работает (может, и давно уже работает...).

Конечно, не `void print(int **mt, int lin, int col);`, а см. **UPD** ответа.