# Ошибка "Нарушение прав доступа при чтении" при попытке разыменовать указатель на указатель, переданный в функцию

Tags: c

Задача:
Пишу код на Си. Есть массив строк, к примеру всего 8 строк по 64 символа, т.е. `char str[8][64]`.
Этот массив заполняется строками, переданными через аргументы командной строки.
Я хочу вывести строки массива str на экран и никаких проблем у меня не возникает, когда я делаю это в функции, где и создавал этот массив.
Я хочу сделать функцию `strArrOut(char **arr, int size)`, которая бы выводила на экран массив строк, когда в неё передают указатель на этот массив  и размер этого массива.

Но когда я пытаюсь разыменовать этот указатель в функции, то получаю ошибку "Нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0xFEFEFEFE", хотя я точно знаю, что по адресу, который содержится в переданном указателе, точно что-то есть.
Долго и упорно гуглил, но наверное я слепой, либо чего-то не понимаю (Хотя по-моему в C++ я делал похожую вещь и обращался к элементам переданного массива через [ ] и всё работало, но тут не получается).

Вот код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void strArrOut(char** arr, int size);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    char str[8][64];
    int strc = argc - 1;

    //Заполняю массив тем, что передано через командную строку
    for (int i = 1; i < strc + 1; i++) {
        strcpy_s(str[i - 1], sizeof(str[i - 1]), argv[i]);
    }

    //Пытаюсь вывести первую строку массива - без ошибок
    printf("p: %p", str);
    printf("\n*p: %s", *str);

    //Пытаюсь вывести первую строку массива, но передавая указатель в функцию
    printf("\nВходные строки: ");
    strArrOut(str, strc);

    return 0;
}

void strArrOut(char** arr, int size) {
    printf("\np: %p", arr); // Выдает тот же адрес, что и str
    printf("\n*p: %s", *arr); // Ошибка: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0xFEFEFEFE
    //printf("\n*p: %s", arr[0]); - выдаёт ту же ошибку
}
```

В чем проблема? Разве я не всегда могу получить значение по адресу, если точно знаю, что за ним есть какое-то значение?

UPD: Рабочее решение: заменить строку `void strArrOut(char** arr, int size);` на `void strArrOut(char arr[][64], int size);`, так всё работает, но всё же интересно было бы услышать предложения почему нельзя разыменовать указатель `char **arr`. При схожей конструкции, но с передачей указателя на одномерный массив (т.е. `char *arr`), разыменовать указатель получается, а тут нет.

Comment: Дело в том, что `char str[8][64]` и `char**str` - два *глубоко* различных типа...

Comment: `void strArrOut(char** arr, int size);` => `void strArrOut(char arr[][64], int size);`

Comment: Спасибо, это сработало. Но всё же интересно, почему выдаёт ошибку при попытке разыменовать указатель.
Harry написал, что `char str[8][64]` и `char **str` различные типы, но ведь `str` представляет собой указатель на указатель на тип char, насколько я помню.

Comment: str - это двумерный массив. Вы просто привыкли к тому, что одномерные массивы могут "деградировать" (decay)  к указателю, но в целом, даже просто массив и указатель - это два разных типа

Comment: [Передать двумерный статический массив в функцию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/464373), [Как передать двумерный массив, созданный на стеке, в функцию, принимающую int**?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/363542), [Почему нужно указывать количество столбцов массива?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1106842), [про многомерные массивы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1248532), [Указатели, ссылки и массивы в C и C++: точки над i](https://habr.com/ru/post/251091/)

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`char** arr` - указатель на указатель `char *`

`char str[8][64]` - массив **char** 8 x 64

`char ( * strp ) [8][64]` - указатель на массив **char** 8 x 64

При передачи массива функции передаётся только адрес на первую строку массива. Копирование не происходит. Можно передавать адрес на *сам* массив. Варианты передачи :

адрес на массив :

```
char str[8][64];

void strArrOut(char (* arrp)[][64], int size) // или

void strArrOut(char (* arrp)[8][64], int size){
  ( * arrp ) [1][2] = 'x' ; }

strArrOut ( & str, strc);
```

адрес на первую строку массива :

```
char str[8][64];

void strArrOut(char arrp[8][64], int size) // или

void strArrOut(char arrp[][64], int size) // или

void strArrOut(char ( * arrp)[64], int size){
  arrp [1][2] = 'x' ; }


strArrOut ( str, strc); // или

strArrOut ( & str[0], strc);
```

---

Как выглядит массив в памяти :

`arr[2][3]` :

```
[0][0] , [0][1] , [0][2] , [1][0] , [1][1] , [1][2]
```

все элементы находятся рядом.

`* * arr` :

```
arr[0] -> [0] , [1] , [2]

arr[1] -> [0] , [1] , [2]
```

`arr` - это массив **указателей**. `arr[i]` - это указатель на строки, эти строки находятся в различных участках памяти.